# mysql print data from specific tables range

Tags: mysql

I have mySQL DB name 'conntrack' with following tables

```
root@Radius:/temp# mysql -uroot -pMYSQLPASS "use conntrack; show tables;"
+------------+
| 2016-11-24 |
| 2016-11-25 |
| 2016-11-26 |
| 2016-11-27 |
| 2016-11-28 |
| 2016-11-29 |
| 2016-11-30 |
+------------+
```

Table have following structure, (example)

```
mysql> describe `2016-12-25`;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| time     | time        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| username | varchar(32) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| srcip    | varchar(15) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| srcport  | varchar(5)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| dstip    | varchar(15) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| dstport  | varchar(5)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| protocol | char(1)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to get dstport fields from table range starting 2016-11-24 to 2016-11-26. How can do it using single liner command?

Comment: Hmmm UNION   

`(SELECT dstport from `2016-11-24`) union (SELECT dstport from `2016-11-27`);`
  
Above command will display data from these two dates only ?
  
or it will get data BETWEEN **24 till 27** ?

Comment: For these two dates only, not for 25-26.

Comment: How can I union or merge result from RANGE (as required in my case)

Tables names are in date format, so I want to get records from table range (liek 2016-11-24 till 2016-11-26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_KEY, COLUMN_DEFAULT, EXTRA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME BETWEEN '2016-11-24' AND '2016-11-26'
```

***Edited***:

```
SET @S = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT DSTPORT FROM `', TABLE_NAME, '`') SEPARATOR ' UNION ') INTO @S
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, 1 AS GRP
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME BETWEEN '2016-11-24' AND '2016-11-26'
) T
GROUP BY GRP;
PREPARE STMT FROM @S;
EXECUTE STMT;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
```

not sure if this is what you want or not, but try it.

Comment: This is showing table structure from both tables,
I want to get dstport column records from both tables (or range of tables)

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib Post your desired result in op please.

Comment: I have updated the question (with your provided command restul as well)

Comment: getting error at  

`mysql> PREPARE STMT FROM @S;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2016-11-24 UNION SELECT DSTPORT FROM 2016-11-26 UNION SELECT DSTPORT FROM 2016-1' at line 1`

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib Updated for backquotes, try again please.

Comment: This worked ! I really appreciate your efforts in replying.  The output its showing is ports list (seems never ending as there are million of entries in it).   What If I dont want  to print the records , instead if it should just show me TOTAL number of records it found ?

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib Of course, you can. But it's another question.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.
I finally managed to get it using One Liner :)
**
use conntrack; SET @S = NULL; SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT count(dstport) FROM `', TABLE_NAME, '`') SEPARATOR ' UNION ') INTO @S FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, 1 AS GRP FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME BETWEEN '2016-11-24' AND '2016-11-24' ) T GROUP BY GRP; PREPARE STMT FROM @S; EXECUTE STMT; DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;"
**